# Your suggestion is great! As it always is

Tags: phrase-request

What is the correct way to say

> Your suggestion is great! As it always is.
>
> Your suggestion is great! As it is always.
>
> Your suggestion is great! As always.
>
> Your suggestion is great! They always are so.

Is any of the above variants correct?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with

> Your suggestion is great, as always.

Your third line is also pretty good:

> Your suggestion is great! As always.

Your first option could be fixed by saying

> Your suggestion is great, as they always are.

or

> Your suggestion is great! As they always are.

Although admittedly it is a little weird to mix "is" and "are" like that.

Presumably, if his suggestions are always good, he has made multiple suggestions in the past, so you should say that they "**are**" great. By contrast, if you say

> Your suggestion is great! As it always is.

it sounds sort of like they have made the same suggestion multiple times, and every time they make that suggestion, that suggestion is great.

Your second line has the same problem, and even if it is fixed to

> Your suggestion is great! As they are always.

It still feels a little unusual to me.

Your last line could be fixed if you wrote

> Your suggestion is great! They always are.

It feels a little unusual to me when you say

> Your suggestion is great! They always are so.

Comment: Agreed! The mixture of **is** and **are** does make the reader a little seasick!